# Unable to open infopath forms when migrated from MOSS 2007 to sharepoint 2010

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

We have migrated MOSS 2007 site to Sharepoint 2010. It consists of Infopath form library. We are able to migrate all versions of the document. New version opens in Infopath 2010 form , but older versions built on Infopath 2007 doesn't open. In version history the old versions are not relinked to the new site. 
Is there any way where I can relink all versions to the new site? 
Can I create a workflow where old versions of infopath forms are converted to pdf?
*Infopath form consists of dataconnections and rules. 
Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Sireesha.

Comment: What do you mean by relink? Are you talking about the URL you put in when you publish a form in InfoPath? Because I believe that URL just serves to confirm you have a valid SharePoint collection and the forms can be used on any SharePoint site regardless of the URL you gave it.

Comment: Also if you can't find an answer here, the guys at http://www.infopathdev.com/ are very knowledgeable about infopath and you can try asking them.

Comment: Relink means when we migrate old forms from MOSS 2007 to sharepoint 2010 , the forms still refer to the MOSS 2007 site where infopath template is published. So, we have to publish new infopath 2010 form template to the sharepoint 2010 site and relink filled infopath forms to the infopath 2010 template location. I am able to open only the latest version, all other versions of the form are still pointing to the old MOSS 2007 site.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue with being unable to open the form when migrating from sharepoint 2007 to 2010.

I finally resolved this issue by doing the following:

1. Open the infopath form
2. Go to Form Option
3. Click on Versioning
4. There is dropdown on right site called as "On Virsion Upgrade"
5. Select "Automatically Upgrade Existing Forms"
6. Publish and upload to Central Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Open the old migrated infopath files in an xml editor or notepad and have a look at wether they still points to the old 2007 server and template.

Comment: Yes, the old versions of the form still points to the MOSS 2007 site. If I change href in the xml to the new infopath 2010 template location in sharepoint 2010 site, then I am able to open the form. Is there any procedure where I can directly convert all versions of the form to link to the new site.

Comment: Please note that *  I am talking about versions of the infopath forms which are already submitted in the MOSS 2007 site. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation when migrating Infopath form libraries between Sharepoint servers. You may find this article of use: [Relink Infopath forms article](http://www.codistri.net/developer/relinking-infopath-forms-during-a-sharepoint-migration)

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problem of not able to open after moving form library from one site collection to another. 
i am sure the issue is with href URL that is there in the xml at this tag.This is still pointing to the old site collection. I tried re-link but didnt worked.

?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:PaidTimeOffRequestForm:-myXSD-2013-05-17T09-07-06" solutionVersion="1.0.0.625" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" **href="http://sp2010/sites/test2/FormServerTemplates/PaidTimeOffRequestForm.xsn**"?>

after i changed the URL and upload the form to library it started working as usual.

Please help me if there is a way to fix this issue.

thank you
raj